# LibGDX 3D: I want some basic collisions with AABB, without using bullet physics

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

My game is basically a 3D dungeon exploration game. The player is a cuboid and **everything it can collide with is a cube aligned in a grid**.

Currently, the player can move around this dungeon and that all works: they *can* move, but they can also move through walls!

The collision handling is done whenever the player moves (i.e. when they press forward, backwards, left or right.) Here's the code for when they press forward.

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(forwardKey)) {
    float totalMove = -moveVelocity; // Total directional movement amount
    /* Therefore ... */ float eachMove = (totalMove / moveParts);
    System.out.println(eachMove);

    for (int i = 0; i < moveParts; i++) {
        BoundingBox newBounds = new BoundingBox(bounds);

        newBounds.set(
                newBounds.min.add(0, 0, -eachMove), 
                newBounds.max.add(0, 0, -eachMove));

        boolean done = false, willCollide = false;
        for (Wall w : Main.currentLevel.getFlattenedWallsArrayList()) {
            if (tryCheckCollision(newBounds, w.getBounds())) {
                // Iff it will collide
                willCollide = true;
                done = true;
            }
            if (done) break;
        }
        if (!willCollide) {
            newVelocity.z += eachMove;
        }
    }
}
```

So this kind of works, but not at all well: you can go forward of course, and when you meet a wall, you stop. However, when you then try to move back from the wall, you can't - this leads me to believe that the player has went too far into the wall, but I can't see how this is possible.

Another thing I need to happen with my collision is that when someone touches a wall, they don't just *stop*, they should continue moving alone the wall if they're looking sort of in that direction.

I'm sure this would be possible with bullet physics, but I don't want to use that since it seems like more effort than it's worth, for my world made of aligned cubes.

**TL;DR:** I need some way of programming the collisions of the player, without using bullet physics.

**EDIT:** Here's the tryCheckCollision method:

```
private boolean tryCheckCollision(BoundingBox checkBounds, BoundingBox collisionBounds) {
    Vector3 center = Vector3.Zero.cpy();
    collisionBounds.getCenter(center);

    if (distanceTo(center) <= maxCollisionCheckDistance) {
        return checkBounds.intersects(collisionBounds);
    }

    return false;
}
```

**EDIT:** And also, `bounds` is the player's bounding box. I update this every frame using this:

```
instance.calculateBoundingBox(bounds);
bounds.mul(instance.transform);
```

Comment: Could you please provide more of your code? How does the `tryCheckCollision()` function work, and am I right to think that your `bounds` variable are the current bounds of your player? If yes, where do you set your `bounds = newBounds`? I have an idea what could be wrong but its hard to tell exactly.

Comment: Please refer to the following page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and update your question.

Comment: @Xoppa it would be difficult to get the code down into a reproducible section, but I will post some more of it, if that helps

Comment: Looking at your code, it's probably more effort for you to make it manually do what you want than it is to use bullet physics. Bullet already contains everything you need and is just a few lines to setup.

Comment: In your edit, what is the `instance.calculateBoundingBox()` method, and where are you getting your `instance.transform` from? Please provide any information that could be useful. The more (relevant) information, the better

Comment: @Xoppa I was looking at a (coincidentally, your) tutorial on this, and that's why I decided it would be too much effort. However, if you think this, you're probably right. Is there a method of using Bullet which would be simpler for use with my game? (the world made entirely out of aligned boxes - comparable to Minecraft)

Comment: @LeonZ. `instance` is an instance of `ModelInstance`. Both `calculateBoundingBox()` and `transform` are members of `ModelInstance`.

Comment: Your `tryCheckCollision()` method just needs to be `return checkBounds.intersects(collisionBounds);`.